# Abstract class implementing an interface doesnt require method implementation. Why?

Tags: java

I am writing a class that is going to implement an interface - The interface has 1 method defined in it. When I write my class definition and write `implements interfaceService` after the class declaration and end my definition and close the brackets of the class WITHOUT overriding the interface method.. It compiles just fine. There is no compilation error and I am able to save the implementing class in Eclipse. Why so? Shouldn't the implementing class be forced to override the method? Here is the interface and implementing class definitions:

Interface:

```
public interface interfaceService{
    List<Map<String, Object>> doSearch(SearchVo formVo,String indexName,String type)
            throws SearchException;
    long getTotalHitCount();
}
```

Class:

```
public abstract class ClientFlagSearch implements SearchService{

}
```

I have a feeling this has to do with defining the implementing class as abstract. Why?

Comment: Any class that extends your abstract class, will have to implement the interface methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Shouldn't the implementing class be forced to override the method?

No, an `abstract` class does not have to implement every method of the interface. Those methods that you choose to not implement remain `abstract` and have to be implemented further down the inheritance tree.

If `ClientFlagSearch` were not `abstract`, it would indeed have to implement every method of `SearchService`.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is **abstract method MUST BE implemented in the first concrete class**

- An `abstract` class doesn't have to implement `abstract` methods
- abstract classes can have abstract methods.

Comment: should be not!, **MUST BE**

Comment: @nachokk aye aye sir.

Answer (score 0):

*Interface* is a collection of abstract methods.

*Abstract class* can have abstract methods.

You don't *need* to implement the interface's methods in your Abstract class, though you can.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html:

> It is possible, however, to define a class that does not implement all of the interface methods, provided that the class is declared to be abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes do not have to implement anything.  This works the same way as it would had you written

```
public abstract class ClientFlagSearch {
    List<Map<String, Object>> doSearch(SearchVo formVo,String indexName,String type)
            throws SearchException;
    long getTotalHitCount();
}
```

Comment: everything -> anything

Comment: Well, yeah.  Changed it.